# third order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Could any experts give me some suggestions on solving this 3 order differential equation?                                                                      $$x'''-x''-(x')(e^{2t})-(x)(e^{2t})=0$$

Comment: Thanks for the edited,but it is e^(2t). Thanks!

Comment: Do you $e^2t$ or $e^{2t}$?  because the $\LaTeX$ for the latter is  \$e^{2t}\$

Comment: It's kinda nasty: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%27%27%27-x%27%27-x%27e%5E(2t)-xe%5E(2t)%3D0

Comment: Thanks very much!!!!!!!!,  I will check it carefully!!!

Comment: Are there conditions ?  As given, the solution provided by WA seems to be difficult to work with.

Comment: I have 3 boundary conditions to bound the solution@ClaudeLeibovici

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce it a little by the trick

$x'''-x''=(x+x')e^{2t}\iff e^{-t}(x'''-x'')=e^t(x'+x)\implies \left(e^{-t}x''\right)'=\left(e^{t}x\right)'$

So you get $x''=e^{2t}x+ce^t$

But I'm afraid that what we got now is not very attractive either...

Comment: The trick is very nice but it makes the problem even more difficult to solve !

Comment: That is enough! Really thanks for your help!!! I will consider it seriously!!!!!@zwim

Comment: It is not more complicated, at least the order decreased, helpful method I think.@ClaudeLeibovici

Comment: Thanks!!!!!!your answer owns the same principle of the experts above!!!Really thanks for answering this problem!!!@ClaudeLeibovici

Answer (score 1):

$$x'''-x''-e^{2t}x'-e^{2t}x=0 \tag 1$$
Change of variable : $\quad z=e^t \quad;\quad \frac{dx}{dt}=z\frac{dx}{dz}\quad;\quad \frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=z^2\frac{d^2x}{dz^2}+z\frac{dx}{dz}\quad;\quad \frac{d^3x}{dt^3}=z^3\frac{d^3x}{dz^3}+3z^2\frac{d^2x}{dz^2}+z\frac{dx}{dz}$

$$\left(z^3\frac{d^3x}{dz^3}+3z^2\frac{d^2x}{dz^2}+z\frac{dx}{dz}\right)-\left(z^2\frac{d^2x}{dz^2}+z\frac{dx}{dz}\right)-z^2\left(z\frac{dx}{dz}\right)-z^2x=0$$
After simplification :
$$z\frac{d^3x}{dz^3}+2\frac{d^2x}{dz^2}-z\frac{dx}{dz}-x=0$$
$$\frac{d}{dz}\left(z\frac{d^2x}{dz^2}+\frac{dx}{dz}-zx\right)=0$$
$$z\frac{d^2x}{dz^2}+\frac{dx}{dz}-zx=c_1$$
$$\frac{d^2x}{dz^2}+\frac1z\frac{dx}{dz}-x=\frac{c_1}{z} \tag 2$$
The homogeneous part is a Bessel ODE which solution is :
$$x_h=c_2J_0(iz)+c_3Y_0(-iz)$$
$J_0$ and $Y_0$ are the Bessel functions of order $0$ and first and second kind.
$$x(z)=c_2J_0(iz)+c_3Y_0(-iz)+c_1x_p(z)$$
The general solution of Eq.$(1)$ is on the form :
$$x(t)=c_2J_0(ie^t)+c_3Y_0(-ie^t)+c_1x_p(e^t)$$

$x_p(z)$ is any particular solution of Eq.$(3)$.
$$\frac{d^2x_p}{dz^2}+\frac1z\frac{dx_p}{dz}-x_p=\frac{1}{z}\tag 3$$
Theoretically it is possible to find $x_p(z)$ thanks to the method of variation of parameters. Let $x_p(z)=f(z)J_0(iz)+g(z)Y_0(-iz)$ and determine $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ so that the reduction of order occurs. This is an awfully arduous task, but possible anyways. Sorry I am too lazy to do it. I let my  faithful slave do the job.

Thanks to WolframAlpha :
$$x_p(z)=\frac{\pi^2}{4}zH_0(iz)J_0(iz)Y_1(-iz)+\frac{\pi^2}{4}zH_{-1}(iz)J_0(iz)Y_0(-iz) +\frac{\pi}{2}zY_0(-iz)\:_2F_1\left(\frac12;1,\frac{3}{2};\frac{z^2}{4} \right)$$
$H_0$ and $H_{-1}$ are Struve functions.

It is probably possible to simplify this horrifying result. But my faithful slave seems so tired that he refuses further calculus.

Comment: Really thanks for your kind help on my problem. You help me so much that i fall to express my words. I will consider your handout carefully and  study hard!!!!@JJacquelin